# "Even though none of you have yet to believe it" — grammatical?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, negation, phrasal-verbs

Is the following sentence from the TV series *American Horror Story* correct, formal grammar?

> We are powerful. Even though none of you have yet to believe it.

In my understanding, it would be "Even though none of you have not yet believed it", which is a double negative.

I have never seen "have yet to" used in negatives.

Comment: It's ungrammatical, like _*They don't remain to be convinced_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> We are powerful, even though none of you have yet to believe it.

Would be a perfectly sensible sentence for dialogue. The first clause states something, "we are powerful" and the second clause modifies that first one, by referring to why that clause may not be already evident.

That second clause "even though none of you have yet to believe it" is reasonable okay as a clause, though incomplete as a sentence.

It is a logically a double negative, and should strictly be "even though all of you have yet to believe it" or "even though none of you believe it yet". It's a reasonable double-negative in dialogue though; it's the sort of thing people would really say, and we know what they mean.

Even as given:

> We are powerful. Even though none of you have yet to believe it.

It's reasonable enough, but the second clause being given as a separate (incomplete) sentence is reasonable as a bit of rhetorical license of making the clause stand more on its own and be considered more fully separate from the first. Or it could show it occurring to the speaking character after they'd already said the first bit.

So while you would normally want to avoid such an incomplete sentence in straight prose, you may deliberately use one in dialogue - your characters don't have to always speak grammatically perfect English - or as rhetorical license.

Comment: Right, but strictly speaking, double negative like this is not grammatical.

Comment: Yes, but strictly speaking, not everybody is strictly speaking. Good dialogue can reflect that without bending so far as to be hard to understand. It's also worth noting that the degree to which English grammar tolerates or disallows double-negatives depends on the form of English, both dialect and register.

Comment: Thanks. Being a non native speaker, I'm trying to learn proper English and thus I need to stick to some rules :)

Comment: Yes, it's not the sort of thing to copy directly, but you should note that no dialogue is. Or at least not yet, too strict adherence to the rules can make some who have English as a second language sound stilted and awkward, but ideally one should still learn them before bending them. You'd also want to bend them in a way appropriate to the time and place you are in, rather than being at a dinner party in Edinburgh or a Hockey game in Vancouver, and sounding like a New Jersey gangster because you watch the Sopranos!

Comment: I disagree that this is a reasonable double negative. It would definitely have thrown me if I'd heard it spoken. Of course I would have understood what was meant from context, but it is noticeably jarring as a double negative. It also seems strange to have something as colloquial as a double negative in a phrase with something as formal as ‘have yet to’.

Comment: Double negatives are **not** ungrammatical. They're all over the place, like the previous sentence. Whoever told you they're "strictly speaking" ungrammatical was simply wrong.

Comment: @JohnLawler: that sounds disingenuous. Double negatives where the meaning is positive are obviously unobjectionable: double negatives where the intended meaning is negative (as in OPs example) are incorrect, though whether you call them *ungrammatical* is a matter of definition.

Comment: Whether you call them "incorrect" is the matter of definition. There are tests for grammaticality, but "correct" is strictly a personal social judgement.

Comment: @John: *Social* possibly, but no more *personal* than "2+2=5 is wrong."

Comment: There are tests for arithmetic, and definitions of correctness there, too. But to say a sentence is "correct" or "incorrect" is a matter of deprecation and taste rather than grammar. It cannot be anything more than personal because deprecation is an emotion.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences starting with *Even* as you have written them are not complete and not correct.

The first does not work; the second still less.

If I look for this on the net, all results come from a *sig* on tumblr.

One cannot use *none* with *yet* as in the example and make sense. You can use *yet* to [state a negative](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/have-yet-to-do-something-):

> We are powerful, even though all (some) of you have yet to believe it.

That works because *yet* in this case means *even though some of you still do not believe it* or *even though some of you have not yet come to this conclusion*

Comment: Exactly that is what I mean but in the TV they said it that way. That is why I ask. none of you have yet = none of you have not yet..double negative

Comment: See my update. I believe the sentences are wrong